# Clicked element of Jquery Collapsable stick to the div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to  make the clicked element of the Jquery Collapsable div make it stick to the header div .

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/6/

This is my code

HTML

```
<div data-role="content" class="data">
        <div class="my-collaspible" data-inset="false"  data-role="collapsible">
            <h3>Header 1</h3>
            <p>Content</p>
            <p>Content</p>

        </div>

         <div class="my-collaspible" data-inset="false"  data-role="collapsible"  >
            <h3>Header 2</h3>
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>

</div>
```

JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.my-collaspible').on('collapsibleexpand', function() {
     var container = $(".my-collaspible");
     container.slideUp(400);
   });
 });
```

I have tried as shown above , but the clicked elemnt is being hidden , i just want to make it stick to the class data

Could you please let me know how to achieve this

http://jsfiddle.net/jWaEv/6/

Comment: If you comment `container.slideUp(400);` line it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks , but this will not stick know .

Comment: I am sorry but I need some more details on your requirement. What do you want to see when you click the header?

Comment: When i click on the header i want to make the clicked elemnet stick to the class by name data .